# Opt in and out buttons based on a certain field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Help with dynamic javascript code. I need code for when the Opt-In date in displayed, the Opt-in button is disabled and the Opt- out button is enabled. When it is not displayed, enable Opt-in button and disable Opt out button. this is my code. I am very new to Javascript. This is what i have so far. thanks

Please choose the following methods to receive notifications

```
<div class="row">
    <form action="AddDataServlet" method="post">

            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label">Phone:</label>

                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" pattern="^[0-9\-\+\s\(\)]*$" placeholder="(123)456-2345"  value="<%=session.getAttribute("Phone")%>">

                </div>
              </div>

             <div class="col-md-2">
             <label class="control-label">OPT-IN DATE:</label>
             <td><input type="datetime" id="OPT-IN phoneDate" name="OPT-IN phoneDate" class="form-control" value="<%=session.getAttribute("PhoneDate")%>"/></td>
             <br>

             </div>


             <div class="col-md-2">
             <br>
            <input type="Submit" class="form-control" value="Opt-In" style ='margin:6px'/>
              </div>
              <script>
            if $(document).ready(function(){
                $('.form-control').attr('disabled',true);

                $('#OPT-IN phoneDate').keyup(function(){
                    if($(this).val().length !=0){
                        $('.form-control').attr('disabled', false);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $('.form-control').attr('disabled', true);        
                    }
                   })                                      
            });
            else if $(document).ready(function(){
                $('.form-control').attr('disabled',false);

                $('#OPT-IN phoneDate').keyup(function(){
                    if($(this).val().length !=0){
                        $('.form-control').attr('disabled', true);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $('.form-control').attr('disabled', false);        
                    }
                   })                                      
            });
             </script>

             <div class="col-md-2">
             <br>
             <input type="button" class="sendButton form-control" value="Opt-Out" style ='margin:6px'></input>

             </div>
```

Comment: you cant use id's with space between !!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, apparently you are really new in javascript :D You need to read more documentations about this langage. But for now, this code should works for you :

Change your input id like that :

```
id="phoneDate"
```

Spaces in ID are not supported, it's for class attribute only.

And in jQuery :

```
$(document).on('ready', function(){
  var $submitButtons = $('.form-control');
  $('#phoneDate').on('keyup', function(){
    var $input = $(this);
    if($input.val() != "") {
      $submitButtons.prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
      $submitButtons.prop('disabled', true);
    }
  });
});
```

And in your rails view, set the initial state like that :

```
<input type="Submit" class="form-control" value="Opt-In" style ='margin:6px' <%= "disabled" if session.getAttribute("PhoneDate").nil? %> />
```

I'm not sure about your issue, but i tried to help you !

Comment: hey thanks for trying. I am still getting errors with your code when i put the code u mentioned in rails view

Comment: It works for me, check your getAttribute('PhoneDate') method, i think something is wrong. Usually i access to my session like that : session[:attribute]